# Best way to make a lot of exceptions in python

Tags: python, exception

I am writing acceptance tests and want to have exceptions in my testing tools that match the product, while still treating it as a black box.

So I have >100 error_codes that are formatted like this.

```
_error_codes = {
    'BAD_NUMBER_FORMAT': 10001,
    'ANOTHER_ONE': 10010,
    'A_BILLION_MORE': 1000000
}
```

And I could create many exceptions in a dictionary with something simple:

```
error_classes = {}

for error in _error_codes:
    the_error = camelize(error.lower()) + 'Error'
    docstring = "A {0} {1} Product_name error.".format(_error_codes[error], error)
    cls_dict = {'__doc__': docstring}
    error_classes[the_error] = (type(the_error, (MyBaseError,), cls_dict))
```

With this I would have to catch exceptions with keys from a dictionary. i.e. 
`except error_classes['AnotherOneError']:`

Is this a pythonic way to do this? Should I instead generate a static file of every class from the _error_codes?

Comment: Here is a tutorial on different ways to handle exceptions : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm

Comment: @imranal I understand exceptions. I am trying to create a couple hundred Exceptions that inherit from one I've built so I can avoid lots of if statements in my exception handling.

Comment: Seems like you would choose which is clearer or less work. Later, you or someone else might appreciate a module with all your custom exceptions spelled out. Maybe you could automate the creation of a module by constructing the strings and writing them to a file.

Comment: The custom exceptions are just specific errors from the API. They are inheriting from my base exception class that pulls out the relevant info from the JSON response. This creation is so that I can do `if self.errorcode in error_classes: raise error_classes[self.errorcode]` and raise the specific error name instead of a generic APIError. I want to handle the exceptions individually instead of doing e.errorcode comparisons in an if/elif/else after catching the base exception.

Comment: It should be the correct type when it is first raised, giving you the option to catch that, or catch one of its bases.

Comment: I think I'm bad at explaining this. It's already the correct type. The actual base class isn't called MyBaseError in my project but the last line ensures that I can catch the generic custom exception and it attaches properties for debugging to the exception. I'm then trying to raise individual errors based on the products exception type. So I got an error from an appliance that raises a MyBaseError Exception type. I want it to raise the specific error that I've grabbed from the appliance. So instead of MyBaseError with attribute message='BAD_NUMBER_FORMAT' I raise BadNumberFormatException.